# How to make dinamically paramname in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I want errors to be written in state without hardcoding parameter names. So I have an object in state `errors: {}` where I want to register errors appearing while form is being filling in.

When error in field `email` it must be `errors: { email: true }`

```
state = {
    errors: {},
    owner: owner.Company,
    fio: null,
    company: null,
    phone: null,
    fax: null,
    email: null,
    adress: null
}

onChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: value, ['errors: ' + e.target.name]: true });
}
```

But in this way the result in state like this

```
errors: {…}
Empty object
errors:company:true
errors:fio:true
errors:phone:true
```

What must the syntax be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing `'errors: ' + e.target.name` you set that parameter name to have the value `true`, but instead you want to add it to your `errors` object.

**Example**

```
onChange = (e) => {
  const { value, name } = e.target;

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    [name]: value,
    errors: { ...prevState.errors, [name]: true }
  }));
};
```

Comment: I made this way:                  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: value, errors: {[e.target.name]: false }}); is it ok?

Comment: @AndrewFleyer If you do it that way, all other properties except `[e.target.name]` in the `errors` object will be removed.

Comment: Yeah!! I've just found this out)))